# Reference for the size of Jordan blocks.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, reference-request, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

Can someone give any reference or pdf to determine the size of Jordan blocks ?

There are some exercises related to the size of Jordan blocks, but I couldn't solve. Any reference will be appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Uniqueness

Comment: Horn and Johnson's Matrix Analysis is one reference that works.  That being said, perhaps you should post one of these exercises as its own question.

Comment: Dummit & Foote is always a good reference.